# Wordpress - Custom Meta Tags controlled from a custom Plugin

Tags: php, seo, wordpress

I have recently built a plugin for Wordpress sort of Special Events & News listing. I have  a listing page and then a detailed page for every news item. Now in the database I have set up 3 columns named meta_title, meta_description and meta_keywords. I also have All in one SEO plugin installed.

Is there a way how from within the plugin (from the loop where I am showing the content), I can say for example `wp_page_meta = $meta_title` or something similar?

As I found some tricks on how to do this by hacking the functions.php and header.php for the theme but this is not the right way.

Comment: You may want to flag this to be moved to the [Wordpress StackExchange Site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out the get_post_meta function in the codex and create custom meta boxes for each event, instead of dealing with the database directly.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta

To add a meta box:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box